# What is the range of the random number generated by this code?

Tags: solidity

```
uint256 seed = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(
            (block.timestamp).add
            (block.difficulty).add
            ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.coinbase)))) / (now)).add
            (block.gaslimit).add
            ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender)))) / (now)).add
            (block.number)
        )));
        seed = seed - ((seed / 10000000) * 10000000) + 1;
```

Is the range of seed 1-100000000, 1-99999999, or something else?

Comment: @Shawn Tabrizi Hi,

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify your code sample to this:

```
uint256 seed = <somthing>;
seed = seed - ((seed / 10000000) * 10000000) + 1;
```

The second line is a complicated way to get the last 7 digits of seed.

The smallest the last 7 digits can be is 0. The largest the last 7 digits can be is 9999999.

Then we add 1, so the range is 1 - 10000000.

A more clear way to do this would be to use the modulo operation:

```
seed = (seed % 10000000) + 1
```

Which has the same results.

Comment: if change seed = (seed % 10000000) + 1 to seed = (seed % 100000000) + 1,then the results. between 1-100000000, right?

Comment: Yes, the range is determined by the number used in the modulo operation. Usually the range is 0 to x - 1, but if you add 1, then you get 1 to x

Comment: the remix ide "Enable Optimization" has some bug?

Comment: when I checked the "Enable Optimization", then go to https://ropsten.etherscan.io/verifyContract2 verify our contract. always wrong